# nodejs delete route warning/confirmation

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, destroy

I'm building a website with nodejs, express and mongoose. I have concerts to be added in using the RESTful routes and comments of users that are connected with those comments.
When I come to the DELETE route, I want the user to be warned instead of deleting a comment directly. Therefore I'm using bootstraps modal.

Anyhow, this worked just fine for tourdates itself, but on the comments that are connected to the tourdates, I get a very strange behaviour on this. Instead of deleting the selected comment, it always deletes the oldest comment. But this is ONLY if I put the bootstraps modal in, without the modal it deletes the right one, even though I don't change anything on the delete form.

Here's the ejs form without the modal (deletes the chosen comment):

```
   <form action="/tourdates/td/<%=concert._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" class="deleteForm">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete">
  </form>
```

That's the same code with the modal (delete's always the oldest comment instead of the chosen one):

```
<form action="/tourdates/td/<%=concert._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" class="deleteForm">
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" href="#collapseDelete" role="button" data-target="#deleteConcertComment">Delete</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteConcertComment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Delete Komment?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure?
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And here's my route:

```
router.delete("/tourdates/td/:id/comments/:comment_id", function(req, res) {
    Comment.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.comment_id, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            req.flash("error", "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            req.flash("success", "Kommentar wurde gelöscht!");
            res.redirect("/tourdates/td/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

I really can't see why the second version deletes the oldest comment in the database instead of the chosen one. And as I said, I have exactly the same thing for the tourdates itself using the route /tourdates/td/:id and there it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Update:

@Neil you're right. My mistake was, that I inspected the delete buttons that I "slotted ahead" before the actual delete button. Since I want this "Are you sure" function, the delete buttons that stick to the single comments won't fire the post request, they shall be fired by the delete-button inside the modal.

Now, if I inspect the delete buttons that are slotted ahead, I see three different forms (one after another) in my inspections view and all of them would trigger different comment id's. But if I click on them, the modal will open and the delete button inside the modal always points to the same id.

Please see the picture, the modal-delete button always points to the same form whilst the single delete-buttons point to different forms. But what do I have to change on my code then? enter image description here

Comment: It's not likely the delete action itself, but rather the data in the form. Most likely is that for some reason you have marked each comment on the form with the same id. Simply hover over the links to confirm and then look at whatever code is processing the template to see the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the hint. But when I inspect the form of the first comment, it shows me the id of the comment in the action=".../id" which is a different id on each comment.